# What is the story of Kalki (tenth avatar of God Vishnu)?

Tags: ramayana, avatars, kalki

I have heard that in Kalki avatar, God Vishnu will marry Goddess Vaishnav devi as promised(*The promise event occurs when God Vishnu were in Ram avatar and returning to Ayodhya after 14 years of exile*). It is also said that Lord Ram has offered his complete army (*including Lord Hanuman*) to protect the Goddess until He re-incarnate as Kalki and marry her.

Apart from this, I know that Kalki Avatar will come on horse to erase corruption and other bad things. So, are there any scriptures which explains the story of Kalki (*a future glimpse*)? please brief it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The Appearance of Lord Kalki (*the Avatar or incarnation of Godhead*) is foretold in the "**Srimad Bhagavatam**" 12th Canto and described also in detail in the "**Brahmanda-purana**". Therein it gives predictions as to where he will appear (*the village name*), who his parents will be, what his mission will be, and when he will appear.
>
> It is described that he will appear at the conjunction of the two yugas, namely at the end of Kali-yuga and the beginning of Satya-yuga. The great cycle of the four yugas, namely Satya, Treta, Dvapara and Kali, rotates like the calendar months. The present age of Kali-yuga lasts 432,000 years, out of which we have passed only 5,000 years after the Battle of Kuruksetra and the end of the regime of King Pariksit. So there are 427,000 years balance yet to be finished, till the advent of Lord Kalki. Therefore at the end of this period, the incarnation of Kalki will take place, as foretold in the Srimad-Bhagavatam. The name of His father, Visnu Yasa, a learned brahmana, and the village Sambhala are also mentioned.
>
> shambhala-grama-mukhyasya brahmanasya mahatmanah    vishnuyashasah
>   kalkih pradurbhavishyati
>
> *"Lord Kalki will appear in the home of the most eminent brahmana of Shambhala village, the great soul Vishnuyasha."*
>
> ashvam ashu-gam aruhya devadattam jagat-patih  asinasadhu-damanam
>   ashtaishvarya-gunanvitah
>
> *"Lord Kalki, the Lord of the universe, will mount His swift horse Devadatta and, sword in hand, travel over the earth exhibiting His eight mystic opulence's and eight special qualities of Godhead."*
>
> vicarann ashuna kshaunyam hayenapratima-dyutih  nripa-linga-cchado
>   dasyun kotisho nihanishyati
>
> *"Displaying His unequalled effulgence and riding with great speed, He will kill by the millions those thieves who have dared dress as kings."*
>
> atha tesham bhavishyanti manamsi vishadani vai  vasudevanga-ragati-
>   punya-gandhanila-sprisham
>   -janapadanam vai hatesv akhila-dasyushu
>
> *"After all the imposter kings have been killed, the residents of the cities and towns will feel the breezes carrying the most sacred fragrance of the sandalwood paste and other decorations of Lord Kalki, and their minds will thereby become transcendentally pure."*
>
> yadavatirno bhagavan kalkir dharma-patir harih  kritam bhavishyati
>   tada praja-sutish ca sattviki
>
> *"When the Supreme Lord Hari [Krishna] has appeared on earth as Kalki, the maintainer of religion, Satya-yuga [the age of truth] will begin, and human society will bring forth progeny in the mode of goodness."*
>
> The mission of Kalki Avatara is to re-establish the religious principles, which have disappeared by the end of Kali Yuga, the iron age of hypocrisy and quarrel.
>
> yada yada hi dharmasya glanir bhavati bharata abhyutthanam adharmasya
>   tadatmanam aham
>
> *"Whenever and wherever there is a decline in religious practice, O descendant of Bharata, and a predominant rise of irreligion--at that time I descend Myself."*
>
> *"In order to deliver the pious and to annihilate the miscreants, as well as to re-establish the principles of religion, I advent Myself millennium after millennium."* [BG 4.7-8]
>
> By the End of Kali Yuga, the population of the whole world will be so much reduced to animalism that there will be no more power to understand what is God, or what is spiritualism. And it is already there, the Kali-yuga. It will increase. People will have no power to understand this philosophy, God consciousness. So at that time, when there are no more religious principles, there is no other alternative than to kill them all.
>
> At that time the Kalki avatara will come, and He'll take a sword on the horseback, just like a king send from heaven, He'll simply go on killing all these non-believers, Godless creatures and usher in another Satya-yuga, the golden age of righteousness and truth.
>
> Kalki avatara is the last of the ten major incarnations of Lord Vishnu who will appear in the end of this Kali Yuga to protect religious principles.
>
> **Kalki: The Next Avatar of God  and the End of Kali-yuga**
>   
> by Stephen Knapp http://www.stephen-knapp.com/
>   
> (An excerpt from The Vedic Prophecies)
>
> The age of Kali-yuga is said to start from the year 3102 BC, after the disappearance of Lord Krishna. Lord Caitanya appeared 500 years ago, at which time the Golden Age within Kali-yuga is supposed to start and last another 10,000 years. As the Golden Age within of Kali-yuga comes to a close, the lower modes of material nature will become so strong that people will lose interest in spiritual topics. It is said that everyone will become godless. Whatever devotees, bhaktas, and sages are left on the planet will be so unique in character and peculiar compared with the rest of society that they will be ridiculed and hunted down in the cities for sport like animals. Thus, they will flee the cities to live underground in caves or high up in the mountains, or simply disengage from the earthly plane of existence. In this way, they will disappear from the face of the earth. That is the time when the dark influence of the age of Kali-yuga will become so dominant that its full influence will manifest without hindrance.
>
> **THE APPEARANCE OF LORD KALKI**
>
> There are many incarnations of the Supreme Being as stated in Srimad-Bhagavatam (1.3.26): "O brahmanas, the incarnations of the Lord are innumerable, like rivulets flowing from inexhaustible sources of water." However, out of all the various incarnations of the Supreme, the Srimad-Bhagavatam (1.3.28) specifically states "krishnas tu bhagavan svayam," which means that Lord Sri Krishna is the original Supreme Personality of God. All others are His plenary portions, or parts of His plenary portions, who descend into this material world to carry out certain responsibilities and to do specific things. This is especially the case when the planets are overly disturbed by miscreants and atheists. In Kali-yuga many years go by in which constant disturbances and social upheavals are allowed to happen, but the Vedic literature predicts that at the end Lord Kalki will make His appearance to change everything, as described in the following verses:
>
> "Thereafter, at the conjunction of two yugas [Kali-yuga and Satya-yuga], the Lord of the creation will take His birth as the Kalki incarnation and become the son of Vishnuyasha. At this time the rulers of the earth will have degenerated into plunderers." (Bhag.1.3.25)
>
> "Lord Kalki will appear in the home of the most eminent brahmana of Shambhala village, the great soul Vishnuyasha." (Bhag.12.2.18)
>
> "At the end of Kali-yuga, when there exist no topics on the subject of God, even at the residences of so-called saints and respectable gentlemen of the three higher castes, and when the power of government is transferred to the hands of ministers elected from the lowborn shudra class or those less than them, and when nothing is known of the techniques of sacrifice, even by word, at that time the Lord will appear as the supreme chastiser." (Bhag.2.7.38)
>
> The Vishnu Purana (Book Four, Chapter 24) also explains that, "When the practices taught in the Vedas and institutes of law have nearly ceased, and the close of the Kali age shall be nigh, a portion of that divine being who exists of His own spiritual nature, and who is the beginning and end, and who comprehends all things, shall descend upon earth. He will be born in the family of Vishnuyasha, an eminent brahmana of Shambhala village, as Kalki, endowed with eight superhuman faculties."
>
> The Agni Purana (16.7-9) also explains that when the non-Aryans who pose as kings begin devouring men who appear righteous and feed on human beings, Kalki, as the son of Vishnuyasha, and Yajnavalkya as His priest and teacher, will destroy these non-Aryans with His weapons. He will establish moral law in the form of the fourfold varnas, or the suitable organization of society in four classes. After that people will return to the path of righteousness.
>
> The Padma Purana (6.71.279-282) relates that Lord Kalki will end the age of Kali and will kill all the wicked mlecchas and, thus, destroy the bad condition of the world. He will gather all of the distinguished brahmanas and will propound the highest truth. He will know all the ways of life that have perished and will remove the prolonged hunger of the genuine brahmanas and the pious. He will be the only ruler of the world that cannot be controlled, and will be the banner of victory and adorable to the world.
>
> Here in these verses we find that Lord Kalki will come as a chastiser or warrior. By this time the planet will be filled with people who will be unable to understand logical conversations. They will be too slow-minded and dull-witted, not capable of being taught much, especially in the way of high philosophy regarding the purpose of life. They will not know what they need to do or how to live. And they certainly will be unable to change their ways. Therefore, Lord Kalki does not come to teach, but simply to chastise, punish, and cleanse the planet.
>
> Furthermore, we also find the name of the place where Lord Kalki will appear and the name of the family in which He will be born. The family will be qualified brahmanas. This means that a disciplic and family line of spiritually qualified brahmanas will remain on the planet throughout the age of Kali, no matter how bad things get. Though they may be hidden, living in a small village somewhere, it will be this line of bhaktas, spiritual devotees, from which Lord Kalki will appear in the distant future. No one knows where this village of Shambala is located. Some feel that it is yet to manifest, or that it will be a hidden underground community from which Lord Kalki will appear.
>
> In this connection we find in the Padma Purana (6.242.8-12) the prediction that Lord Kalki will be born in the town of Shambala near the end of Kali-yuga from a brahmana who is actually an incarnation of Svayambhuva Manu. It is described that Svayambhuva performed austerities at Naimisa on the bank of the Gomati River for acquiring the privilege of having Lord Vishnu as his son in three lifetimes. Lord Vishnu, being pleased with Svayambhuva, granted the blessing that He would appear as Svayambhuva's son as Lord Rama, Krishna, and Kalki. Thus, Svayambhuva would appear as Dasaratha, Vasudeva, and then Vishnuyasha. Also, in the Padma Purana (1.40.46) we find Lord Vishnu admits that He will be born in Kali-yuga. Thus, He will appear as Lord Kalki.
>
> The Srimad-Bhagavatam (12.2.19-20) describes Lord Kalki's activities as follows: "Lord Kalki, the Lord of the universe, will mount His swift white horse Devadatta and, sword in hand, travel over the earth exhibiting His eight mystic opulences and eight special qualities of Godhead. Displaying His unequaled effulgence and riding with great speed, He will kill by the millions those thieves who have dared dress as kings."
>
> **THE ACTIVITIES OF LORD KALKI**
>
> We should make note here that, as the Vedic literature explains, when the Supreme kills anyone, that person is immediately spiritually purified by His touch and because the person is focused on the Supreme Being while leaving his body. Thus, that person attains the same destination as those yogis who spend years steadying the mind in order to meditate and leave their bodies while focused on the Supreme. So being killed by the Supreme is a great advantage for those of a demoniac mentality who would otherwise enter lower realms of existence or even the hellish planets in their next lives.
>
> The Vishnu Purana (Book Four, Chapter 24) continues to explain Lord Kalki's activities: "By His irresistible might he will destroy all the mlecchas and thieves, and all whose minds are devoted to iniquity. He will reestablish righteousness upon earth, and the minds of those who live at the end of the Kali age shall be awakened, and shall be as clear as crystal. The men who are thus changed by virtue of that peculiar time shall be as the seeds of human beings, and shall give birth to a race who will follow the laws of the Krita age [Satya-yuga], the age of purity. As it is said, 'When the sun and moon, and the lunar asterism Tishya, and the planet Jupiter, are in one mansion, the Krita age shall return.'" The Agni Purana (16.10) also relates that Hari, after giving up the form of Kalki, will go to heaven. Then the Krita or Satya-yuga will return as before.
>
> Additional information that can help us understand the activities of the next coming of God is found in the Linga Purana (40.50-92), the Brahmanda Purana (1.2.31.76-106 & 2.3.73.104-126), and the Vayu Purana (58.75-110). In these texts we find descriptions of Lord Kalki as He will appear in the future and also as how He appeared in previous incarnations as Pramiti in this time period known as the Svayambhuva Manvantara. These texts tell us that as Kali-yuga comes to a close, and after the death of Bhrigu (or in order to slay the Bhrigus), Kalki (Pramiti) took birth in the Lunar dynasty of Manu. He will wander over the planet without being seen by any living being. Then he will start His campaign in His thirty-second year and roam the earth for twenty years. He will take with Him a big army of horses, chariots, and elephants, surrounded by hundreds and thousands of spiritually purified brahmanas armed with weapons. [Being brahmanas, these weapons may be brahminical weapons that are activated by mantras, such as the powerful brahmastra rather than base weapons of combat such as knives, swords, and spears, or even guns and ordinary explosives.] Though they may try to do battle with Him, He will kill all of the heretics [and false prophets] and wicked, mleccha kings.
>
> In a previous incarnation He killed the Udicyas (Northerners), Madhya Deshyas (residents of the middle lands), Purvatiyas (mountain dwellers), Pracyas (Easterners), Praticyas (Westerners), Dakshinatyas (of Southern India), the Simhalas (Sri Lankans), Pahlavas (the fair-skinned nomadic tribes of the Caucasus mountains), Yadavas, Tusharas (people of the area of Mandhata, India, or present day Tukharistan), Cinas (Chinese), Shulikas, Khashas, and different tribes of the Kiratas (aboriginal tribes living in north-eastern India and Nepal) and Vrishalas.
>
> No one could stop Him as He wielded His discus and killed all the barbarians. When He was finished He rested in the middle land between the Ganges and Yamuna with His ministers and followers. He allowed only a few people to remain, scattered over the planet. These would be as seeds for the next generations that would follow in the next Satya-yuga. Thereafter, when Lord Kalki has made way for the next age of Satya-yuga, and delivered the earth and whatever is left of civilization from the effects of Kali-yuga, He will go back to His eternal abode along with His army.
>
> Continuing with the description of Lord Kalki as described in the Linga, Brahmanda, and Vayu Puranas, they explain that after Lord Kalki returns to His eternal abode, when those subjects surviving at the end of Kali-yuga are enlightened, the yuga changes overnight. Then the minds of all people will become enlightened, and with inevitable force Krita or Satya-yuga sets in. People will then realize the soul, and acquire piety, devotion, tranquility, and clear consciousness. Then those Siddhas [the enlightened and perfected living beings who had remained invisible on a higher dimension through the end of the age of Kali] return to the earthly dimension and again are clearly visible. They establish themselves with the return of the Saptarishis, the seven sages, who instruct everyone about spiritual life, Vedic knowledge, and the progressive organization of society for a peaceful and fulfilling existence. Then again people flourish and perform the sacred rites, and the sages will remain in authority to continue the advancement of the new Satya-yuga.

Sources:

1. [The Philosophy Of Understanding The Supreme by Urdhvaga das](https://www.yoga-philosophy.com/eng/bookindex.htm)

   - [The Appearance of Kalki Avatar](https://www.yoga-philosophy.com/eng/kalki.htm)
2. [Kalki: The Next Avatar of God and the End of Kali-yuga by Stephen Knapp](https://www.stephen-knapp.com/kalki_the_next_avatar_of_God.htm)

Comment: This looks like copy-paste. If it is, you should add proper attribution.

Comment: This is from a pdf file  on  my lap. I don't  know the original source... I've added the author.

Comment: I've added the author

Comment: @KiranRS add ebook name too.

Answer (score 2):

Lord has to come on Indian soil with the name of Kalki, in village Shambhal Gram and people will call Him with many different community names. In Agastya Samhitā, Agastya Rishi called Him with 1000 different names. Vārāha Purāna, Chapter 48, Page No 94 called with 7 (seven) different names, Mahabharat, Vana Parva called Him with the name of Kalki Vishnu Yasha and Shrimad Bhagawata Maha Purana has also called Him with different name i.e. secret.

Since He is King of Kings, GOD of Gods and Universal thus He cannot be for one particular religion. He is for Hindu, He is for Islamic people, He is for Christian and at the same time He is for Sikh also. There is no God except Him. One is He, no partner hath He. Exalted is He alone, and praise be to Lord Kalki only, and there is no deity except Lord Kalki, and Lord Kalki is the Greatest. And there is no might nor power except in [Lord Kalki](http://kalkimahaavatar.in/), the Most High, the Most Great. He gives life and causes death, and He is Living, who will not die, never. He of Majesty and Munificence. Within His Hand is (all) good. And He is, upon everything, Able (to exert His Will).
For more info visit our website : kalkimahaavatar.in

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are and in Mahabharata, Markandeya tells the Pandavas how Kalki will be born and what he will do and his story.

This is what Kalki will do before another Satya Yuga begins.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm

> And commissioned by Time, a Brahmana of the name of Kalki will take his birth. And he will glorify Vishnu and possess great energy, great intelligence, and great prowess. And he will take his birth in a town of the name of Sambhala in an auspicious Brahmana family. And vehicles and weapons, and warriors and arms, and coats of mail will be at his disposal as soon as he will think of them. And he will be the king of kings, and ever victorious with the strength of virtue. And he will restore order and peace in this world crowded with creatures and contradictory in its course. And that blazing Brahmana of mighty intellect, having appeared, will destroy all things. And he will be the Destroyer of all, and will inaugurate a new Yuga. And surrounded by the Brahmanas, that Brahmana will exterminate all the mlecchas wherever those low and despicable persons may take refuge."

---

He will later conduct a horse sacrifice.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03190.htm

> "Markandeya continued, 'Having exterminated the thieves and robbers, Kalki will, at a great Horse-sacrifice, duly give away this earth to the Brahmanas, and having established anew the blessed rectitude ordained by the Self-create, Kalki, of sacred deeds and illustrious reputation, will enter a delightful forest, and the people of this earth will imitate his conduct, and when the Brahmanas will have exterminated the thieves and robbers, there will be prosperity everywhere (on earth). And as the countries of the earth will one after another be subjugated, that tiger among Brahmanas, Kalki, having placed deer skins and lances and tridents there, will roam over the earth, adored by foremost Brahmanas and showing his regard for them and engaged all the while in slaughtering thieves and robbers. And he will exterminate the thieves and robbers amid heart-rending cries of 'Oh, father--' 'Oh, mother!--'O son!' and the like, and O Bharata, when sin will thus have been rooted out and virtue will flourish on arrival of the Krita age, men will once more betake themselves to the practice of religious rites.

In conclusion, Kalki avatar will come at the end of Kali Yuga to establish Dharma by killing sinners, conduct horse-sacrifce and kill the remaining thieves and robbers. After doing all this, virtue will flourish when the Krita Yuga starts. That is or will be his story.