# When will the Kalki avatar be born?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, kalki

Kalki avataar is the avatar of lord Vishnu. It is said that Kalki Avatar will born in Kaliyug.

Is there any specific date or time which describes Kalki's birth?

Comment: [Related] [What is the story of Kalki (tenth avatar of God Vishnu)?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/579/93)

Comment: According to the scriptures kalki is the final avatar of Lord Vishnu of this Chatur youga cycle and he will appear at the end of this Kaliyuga whhich is about 432,000 years away. By that time Dharma on earth will have declined upto like 99% and there will be evil ness most of everywhere on earth.

Comment: Lord Vishnu's tenth avatar Kalki will be born during 21st century when the whole world will spread with crimes. During that time,the world war-3 will also happen. His guru will be the great sage Parashurama who is still meditating in this Kali Yuga. One day he will destroy all crimes of the world and he will also kill the evil people like terrorists,kidnappers etc. He will have a sword in his hand and he will sit on a powerful horse. He will have such powers that can kill every humans,animals,birds etc.

Answer (score 17):

Wikipedia quotes:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalki

South Indian astrologers have analyzed Puranas extensively to try and foretell the time of birth of Kalki. The signs described in the Kalki Purana are as follows:

The moon will be in Dhanishtha nakshatra, Aquarius, suggesting he will be wealthy, acclaimed and swift in action and thought.

The sun will be in Swati, the nakshatra of the sword.

Jupiter will be in Purva Ashadha nakshatra, Sagittarius.

The Ascendant Lord will be in Purva Ashadha nakshatra, also Sagittarius, suggesting invincibility and early victory.

Saturn will be exalted in Libra, predicting a balance between justice and the sword.

Ketu, lord of horse-headed Ashwini, will be exalted in Scorpio, suggesting he will descend atop a great white steed.

His arrival is stipulated at a time when the earth is engulfed in crisis because of a tyrannical and powerful ruler. Kalki Bhagwan is said to be mounted on a strikingly beautiful White Horse, and is most often picturised in the foreground of a dark sky. This symbolises his coming at a time when darkness (evil) is the order of the day, and he is the saviour to rid the world of its sufferings. This is similar to the Parashuram avatar, where Lord Vishnu killed the atrocious Kshatriya rulers.

The Kalki Avatar is the most eagerly awaited one, more so because it will signify the cleansing of the world from all its sorrows that have been accumulated for many millennia. He is to arrive at the end of Kalyug, the dark age, and will mark the beginning of the Sat Yug. According to calculations, there are still many years left for that to happen (The Kalyug extends for a period of 432000 years, and it has just started - 5000 years ago). When we have such advanced military technology today, it will be interesting to see (though we may not, unless we do not manage to attain salvation by then, and are still caught in the rebirth cycle) what kind of weapons Kalki Avatar utilises.

It is also said that Kalki avtar will come, when all the three rivers Saraswati, Yamuna and Ganga return to heavens ( dried).

The earliest reference to the Kalki Avatar is found in the India's great epic, the Mahabharat. Rishi Markandeya tells Yudhishtir, the seniormost Pandava, that Kalki will be born to Brahmin parents. He would excel in academics, sports and warfare, and thus become a very intelligent and powerful young man.

Kalki Puranam tells that he will stay for some time in Simhala Dwipa (Sri Lanka) and then return to India. Very minute details about his wife and children are mentioned. There are portions which have a literal connotation and there are also portions which have a symbolic connotation. The symbolic method was given by God so that the false ones who claim themselves as God will get caught when they try to fit themselves into his role. This method was reserved for another purpose also. It was done to prevent the Vedas from being destroyed by the atheists. Kalki Puranam also tells about all the deeds that Kalki Maha Avatar will accomplish. They tell us how he will confront 'Kali Purushan' directly and annihilate him. They also tell how he will ascend to heaven after his divine purpose is accomplished.

It also mentions that he will be born in Sambala Gramam. So Sambala Gramam must be near Tamirabarani according to these texts and not in North India as is popularly believed.

Bhagawatham, Canto II, Chapter 5: Text 39-40 as follows: "Very few people are found to follow and worship Narayana in Kali-Yuga. Simple and insignificant people are found worshipping Lord Narayana in "DRAVIDA-DESHAM" (TAMIL NADU) in a place where River TAMIRAPARNEE will be flowing (TIRUNELVELI)".

This is a very clear cut prophecy. So it can be understood that the final KALKI MAHA AVATAR will have his abode on the outskirts of River Tamiraparnee, which is in Tamil Nadu.

The astronomical positions of the stars and planets now is not the same as it was in the antediluvian world when the Pole Star was right on top of Mount Meru. Kanchi Peedam asserts this most categorically. As the world is now tilted at an angle of twenty three and half degrees the configuration of the stars and planets at the time of birth of Kalki Maha Avatar will not be the same as stated in the texts when a different configuration was applicable.

[Source](http://www.prabhupada.org.uk/kalki.htm).

Comment: That is quite nicely explained. Is the name name Kali-yug synonymous with kalki itself? do they have any relation?

Comment: Kaliyug is started after the death of Lord Krishna, on other hand , kalyug started.

Comment: "The Kalyug extends for a period of 432000 years, and it has just started - 5000 years ago" This was introduced by AryaBhatta, and he artificially inflated the numbers by multiplying by a factor of 360. The KalaChakra calculations (supported by Tantrik Masters, and Master Astrologers) which come from Jyotiṣa/Astronomy/"Astrology" clearly indicate that the complete Yuga cycle is 25,860 years long, which is the time it takes for the Vernal Equinox to move from Ashwini to Revati to Uttara Bhadrapada to ...... back to Ashwini.

Answer (score 6):

**Kalki is supposed to be born in the *Kritayuga (Satyuga)*** which would be commenced after a *Kaliyuga*. At the end of Kaliyuga most of the humanity will be destroyed and will start afresh. Here is that story from [Vana Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm), during which Rishi Markendeya explains it to Yudhishtira.

> ... And when those terrible times will be over, **the creation will begin anew. And men will again be created and distributed into the four orders beginning with Brahmanas**. And about that time, in order that men may increase, Providence, according to its pleasure, will once more become propitious. And then when the Sun, the Moon, and Vrihaspati will, with the constellation Pushya 1, enter the same sign, **the Krita age will begin again**. And the clouds will commence to shower seasonably, and the stars and stellar conjunctions will become auspicious. And the planets, duly revolving in their orbits, will become exceedingly propitious. And all around, there will be prosperity and abundance and health and peace. **And commissioned by Time, a Brahmana of the name of Kalki will take his birth**. And he will glorify Vishnu and possess great energy, great intelligence, and great prowess. And he will take his **birth in a town of the name of Sambhala** in an auspicious Brahmana family. And vehicles and weapons, and warriors and arms, and coats of mail will be at his disposal as soon as he will think of them. And he will be the king of kings, and ever victorious with the strength of virtue. And he will **restore order and peace in this world** crowded with creatures and contradictory in its course. And that blazing Brahmana of mighty intellect, having appeared, will destroy all things. And he will be the Destroyer of all, and will inaugurate a new Yuga. And surrounded by the Brahmanas, that Brahmana will exterminate all the mlecchas wherever those low and despicable persons may take refuge."

Also refer:

- [When will the Kalyug end? Are there symbols written in scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19602/1049)
- [What are the four legs of Dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19601/1049)

Comment: Oh nice finding... I always supposed Kalki will be born in Kaliyuga...

Comment: It does not say a Krita Yuga followed by a Kali Yuga.  It's just referring to the fact that Kalki's birth marks the end of the Kali Yuga and the beginning of the Satya Yuga.

Comment: The chapter does not say that all the evil people will die before the birth of Kalki.  But the main problem with your answer is that you say "the Kritayuga (Satyuga) which is followed by a Kaliyug".  That makes it sound as if the Kali Yuga comes after the Satya Yuga.  Did you mean to say "which follows" rather than "which is followed by"?

Comment: @Tezz Kalki will be born during Sandhyamsa period of Kali and Satya.

Comment: @gansub, that's the purpose of the answer. There are many contradictory theory around Kalki and hence it should be taken with grain of salt. BTW, another way of interpreting is that, Kalki will born after *kaliyuga* and restore the order; this times will incidentally be the next *satyuga*. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Kalki; the last incernation of Lord Vishnu will come when kaliyug will running at it's end the situations will be completely changed. People will stop to follow Vedas and everyone will engage in crime

- Srimand bhagwatam 12:2:12-16

  > When the bodies of all living entities are in decay from the contamination of Kali-yuga, when the dutifulness of the members of all status-orientations is lost, when the Vedic path for all man has changed into a predominantly atheistic sense of duty, when the kings mainly consist of thieves and the people in their various occupations are lying criminals of useless violence [against specially animals], when the societal classes as good as all are engaged in profit-minded labor, cows have the same value as goats, the hermitages hardly can be distinguished from materialistic households, family bonds do not reach beyond the ties of marriage, when the plants and herbs are mostly small sized and all trees are like s'amî trees, when there is always lightning in the clouds and the homes are ruled by loneliness [voidism, impersonalism, see Pranâti], when Kali-yuga is running at its end and the people behave like asses, **the Supreme Lord will descend in the mode of pure goodness to defend the dharma.**

Kalki avatar will bring the end of evil people and period **Kaliyug**

- Srimad Bhagwatam 12:2:17

  > The spiritual master of all the moving and nonmoving living beings, Lord Vishnu, the Supreme Personality and Controller of All, takes birth for the protection of the religion and **to put an end to the karma of the saintly souls.**

As per the shastras, kaliyug was started in 3102 BC. Kaliyug is 4,32,000 years long. 5121 years are passed.

**4,32,000-5121=426879 years

**After 426879 years, kalki avatar will come.**

Comment: Is it something common in India to leave out the zero? 4.320.000 is the number regularly used.

Comment: @Wikash what do you want to say.

Comment: Well did you mean 4.320.000 years? Did you accidentally leave out the zero?

Comment: In Indian no. System, we write it like this.