# ISR says birthdate of Lord Rama is 10th January 5114 BC. What about Kalki avatar?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, history, rama, kalki

As per [ISR scientific study and research](http://zeenews.india.com/news/nation/lord-ramas-date-of-birth-scientifically-calculated_796118.html), Lord Rama's birth date is calculated as 10<sup>th</sup> january 5114 BCE. They used a software named Planetorium, simulated arrangement of planets as per Valmiki Ramayana and determined that the same arrangement of planets existed in 5114 BCE.

Note the position of stars at the time of Rama's birth that Valmiki states in Ramayana Bala Kanda, [Sarga 18](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga18/balasans18.htm#Verse8), Shlokas 8-11:

> ततो यज्ञे समाप्ते तु ऋतूनाम् षट् समत्ययुः | 
>   ततः च द्वादशे मासे चैत्रे नावमिके तिथौ || १-१८-८
>
> नक्क्षत्रे अदिति दैवत्ये स्व उच्छ संस्थेषु पंचसु | 
>   ग्रहेषु कर्कटे लग्ने वाक्पता इंदुना सह || १-१८-९
>
> प्रोद्यमाने जगन्नाथम् सर्व लोक नमस्कृतम् | 
>   कौसल्या अजनयत् रामम् सर्व लक्षण संयुतम् || १-१८-१०
>
> विष्णोः अर्धम् महाभागम् पुत्रम् ऐक्ष्वाकु नंदनम् | 
>   लोहिताक्षम् महाबाहुम् रक्त ओष्टम् दुंदुभि स्वनम् || १-१८-११
>
> On completion of the ritual, six seasons have passed by; then in the twelfth month, i.e., in chaitra mAsa, and on the **ninth day of that chaitra month** [April-May], when it is punarvasu nakshatra yukta navamI tithi, i.e., when the ruling star of that ninth day is **punarvasu**, for which Aditi is the presiding deity; and when five of the nine planets - **sUrya**, **kuja**, **guru**, **shukra**, **shani** are in ucCha sthAna-s, namely, when those planets are in ascension in their respective houses - meSha, makara, karkaTa, mIna, tula - rAshI-s; and when **chandra yukta guru, karkaTa lagne** - Jupiter in conjuction with Moon is ascendant in Cancer, and when day is advancing, Queen Kausalya gave birth to a son with all the divine attributes like lotus-red eyes, lengthy arms, roseate lips, voice like drumbeat, and who took birth to delight the Ikshwaku dynasty and adored by all the worlds, and who is the greatly blessed epitome of Vishnu, namely Rama. [1-18-8, 9, 10, 11]

<sub>To summarize, the conditions were:</sub>

1. <sub>9th day after New Moon in Chaitra Lunar Month</sub>
2. <sub>Moon was in Punarvasu Nakshatra (20 deg Gemini to 3.20 deg Cancer)</sub>
3. <sub>Sun in Aries (Su "exaltation" sign is Aries)</sub>
4. <sub>Mars in Capricorn (Ma "exaltation" sign is Capricorn)</sub>
5. <sub>Saturn in Libra (Sa "exaltation" sign is Libra)</sub>
6. <sub>Jupiter in Cancer (Ju "exaltation" sign is Cancer)</sub>
7. <sub>Venus in Pisces (Ve "exaltation" sign is Pisces)</sub>
8. <sub>As soon as Moon moved closer to Jupiter and Cancer rose on the Horizon (East Direction / Lagna / First House in Vedic Astrology), Shri Rama was born</sub>

<sub>Also they validated all the incidents like Bharata's date of birth, Hanuman visiting Lanka to find Seeta that time Lunar Eclipse took place. All of these dates were validated and their research concluded that Rama existed in 5114 BC.</sub>

<sub>Following is the image of planets in Planetorium software when Rama took birth.</sub>

[image: rama]

<sub>Also they found the date of Mahabharata to be some 3000 BC.</sub>

---

**Questions:**

Current year is 2015. So 7000 years before now, Lord Rama existed and you can see the difference between Lord Rama (Treta-yuga) and Mahabharata (Dwapara-yuga) is only 2000 years scientifically. Then why Kaliyuga is lasting from 5000 years? Is this true as per Hinduism?

**Also, are locations or arrangments of planets mentioned for Kalki avatar's birth or pralaya in any other purana?**

**If it is there, can we simulate in planetorium software and find out when Kalki will be born?**

---

<sub>References:</sub>

1. <sub>[Quora.com: When & Where was Lord Rama born and what evidence is there to substantiate this?](https://www.quora.com/When-Where-was-Lord-Rama-born-and-what-evidence-is-there-to-substantiate-this)</sub>
2. <sub>[sarojbala.blogspot.in: Scientific Dating of Ramayana](http://sarojbala.blogspot.in/2012/06/scientific-dating-of-ramayan-era.html)</sub>
3. <sub>[sarojbala.blogspot.in: Slides on Astronomical dating of events in Ramayana](http://sarojbala.blogspot.in/2015/10/amazing-facts-about-ancient-india_22.html)</sub>

Comment: Nice software & research but will the position of astrological/astronomical objects be same only once or at specific time intervals. I think the answer should be latter one and then it will become confusing whether the events we are discussing happened on last instance of their occurrence or on any other one. Btw, scientists have claimed that if they know the century in which Mahabharata happened then they would give the exact date of Jayadrath vadh as it was full solar eclipse then which repeats after a certain period but they have nothing to find the century in which it would have happened.

Comment: Thanks aby, but in this research they have found everything. even mahabharta war also.

Comment: I agree with @Aby - the positions of the stars can recur.

Comment: I think this software is still helpful as all series of events donot occur on same interval. eg, if Event A occurs after every 2 years and Event B occurs every 5 years and they actually fall within the same year or at a difference of X years in Ramayana or Mahabharata, and if that series matches with that of the software then things can be validated. Even I think that the time span, and units of days, months, years, yugas, Mahayugas, etc being shown in texts are either different from units we use today or they are exaggerated.

Comment: Very nice question; I always wanted to ask. @KeshavSrinivasan, I had seen this references sometime back and I will agree more on the scientific research. This should also put a stop on the speculation based theories where Rama existed in Xth Treta Yuga and having a life span of 10k years. Even if exact planet position may recur (less likely though), the hard details like Ramsetu cannot be retained for lacs of years as it is. Already proven that, Indian plato is rushing towards Himalaya every year. If Rama existed lacs of years back, then Ramsetu would have been detached far more than now.

Comment: @iammilind Geological timescales are pretty long, and the distance between India and Sri Lanka is several orders of magnitudes bigger than the plate shifts.  So I don't think hundreds of thousands of years would pose a problem. And in any case, planet positions can easily recur with high frequency, especially since our scriptures don't give the exact degree positions of the planets, only their positions relative to the 12 Rashis and the like.  So the Ramayana definitely happened more than 2000 years before the Mahabharata.  The statements in our scriptures should be taken seriously.

Comment: You can ask this question on the Astrology SE proposal to get a more detailed answer: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101512/vedic-astrology?referrer=WNGAY2D0NY672-MEPBo36A2

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan One position could recur, second could recur, third could recur but the whole sequence cannot recur and that too in perfect tandem. Have a look at [this article](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Lord-Ram-was-born-in-5114-BC/articleshow/273107.cms).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Also [read this](http://greatindiandiscoveries.blogspot.in/2007/11/was-ram-born-on-10th-january-5114-bce.html), now I'm sure you have to agree to this theory. All dates are consistent.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I made some edits so it will look more like a Qn of Kalki instead of Rama or Ramayana. Maybe you should trim down the question a bit. Why to go extensively over Rama's birth when your question is about Kalki?

Comment: ISR is totally wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When will the Kalki avatar be born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/when-will-the-kalki-avatar-be-born)

Comment: ISR is not conclusive. If we follow the argument, Sri Rama was born 7000 years ago - then the entire epic Ramayana is false - for in the first sarga of Bala Kanda  stanza 97 it says :दशवर्षसहस्त्राणि दशवर्षशतानि च |
    रामो राज्यमुपासित्वा ब्रह्मलोकं प्रयास्यति ||                          Sri Rama shall rule 11000 years and that period has not elapsed since 5114 BCE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my view the above study went wrong.  My opinion on this issue is as follows:

1)      According to the Scientific dating conducted by many scholars, The Great War of Mahabharat between the Pandavas and the Kauravas happened in 3139 BC. The Pandavas, after winning the Mahabharat war, ruled Hastinapur for 36 years and 8 months until the beginning of kaliyug in 3102 BC.

2)    Srimad Ramayana was written much earlier to Mahabharata.  In the 272-289 Sections of Vana Parva of Mahabharata, the story of Sri Rama was narrated  to Yuddhistara by Sage Markandeya.   Though the story contains minor variations compared to the story told in the Srimad Ramayana, those episodes describe the story of Sri Rama in full. As the story of Sri Rama was narrated in full to Yuddhisthira in Mahabharata, we can safely conclude that Srimad Ramayana was written much earlier to Mahabharata.

3)   The story of Srimad Ramayana ends with Sri Rama's coronation as the King of Kosala Kingdom.  Sage Valmiki describes in the concluding chapter of Yuddha Kanda that having enjoyed the kingship for ten thousand years, Sri Rama performed a hundred horse-sacrifices.   It was described very briefly about the happy life of the people of Kosala kingdom during the reign of Sri Rama.

सर्वे लक्षणसम्पन्नाः सर्वे धर्मपरायणाः ||
दशवर्षसहस्राणि रामो राज्यमकारयत् |   (Yuddha Kanda 128 Sarga 106 Sloka)

"All the people were endowed with excellent characteristics. All were engaged in virtue. Rama was engaged in the kingship thus **for Ten thousand years."

4)  If we take 3102 BC as the basis for the Mahabharata dating, then at least 10,000 years are to be added, assuming that Mahabharata immediately followed Sri Rama,  to 3102 BC for getting the age of Sri Rama.  Thus, we will get 13,102 BC.  That means atleast 15,000 years back Srimad Ramayana might have written.

This was the available calculation.

Comment: This is scientifically proven Ramayana. This is nice effort. It has proofs. Your calculations of "Early" has no proofs.

Comment: Mere quoting of Astronomy does not make a paper SCIENTIFIC.  If we believe Srimad Ramayana, then we have to take in to consideration that Sri Rama ruled 10,000 years and this period, along with the age of Mahabharata i.e, 3139 B.C. have to fit in the SCIENTIFIC paper.

Comment: cite source which says so. You should cite sources for this comment.

Comment: What source do you want?  be explicit

Comment: source of what you are saying.

Comment: As far as Sri Rama's ruling Kosala Kingdom is concerned for 10,000 years, it was already mentioned in my posting.  I quoted the sloka and Sarga in Srimad Ramayana.

Comment: In respect of Mahabharata period please go through the URL.http://www.hindunet.org/hindu_history/ancient/mahabharat/mahab_vartak.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29925/discussion-between-srimannarayana-k-v-and-parth-trivedi).

Comment: Between Science and Scriptures - Rama Ravana war was fought in the 24th Treta Yuga and we are currently in the 28th Kali Yuga. As per Pauranic calculations a Maha Yuga comprises of 43,20,000 human years, interpreting the 12,000 years of a Maha Yuga as Deva Years [ each day being equal to one human year and the year having 360 days] while other scholars interpret it as 12,000 human years. the software Planetarium can go back 99,000 years only - is it possible that in these 99,000 years only once the astral chart matched - scientifically every 25,000 years the galaxies return to starting point.