# Did lord Krishna took Avatar when sons of Shatrughna were king of Mathura?

Tags: krishna, ramayana, avatars

I heard like lord Rama had two sons, similarly all other brothers had also two sons each. I would like to know their names.

Later two sons of Shatrughna become king separately at Mathura and Brij.

Did lord Krishna took Avatar when sons of Shatrughna were king of Mathura in their period?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sons of Rama and their kingdom**

Kusha (Kusi) and Luva (Lava)

> [Uttara Kanda of Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-121)
>
> The intelligent Rama has reared for Kusha the spacious city of Kusavati at the foot of the Vindhya range.
>
> The city of Sravanti has been reared for Lava.
>
> The mighty car warriors Rama and Bharata, making Ayodhya void of men,
> have addressed themselves for preparing to heaven.

**Sons of Bharata and their kingdom**

Taksha and Pushkala

> [Uttara Kanda of Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-114)
>
> Bharata placed Taksha in Takshasila and Pushkala in Pushkalavati.

**Sons of Lakshmana and their kingdom**

Angada and Chandraketu

> [Uttara Kanda of Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-115)
>
> The beautiful country of Chandra dyuti be the kingdom of Chandraketu and having brought the country of Karupada under his subjection gave it to Angada.

**Sons of Shatrughna and their kingdom**

Shatrughati (Satrughati) and Subahu (Suvahu)

> [Uttara Kanda of Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-121)
>
> Suvahu was placed on the throne of Mathura and Satrughati became the king of Vidisha.

**Did lord Krishna took Avatar when sons of Shatrughna were king of Mathura?**

No, please see the explanation here:

[Ramayana ➡ Mahabharata: 31 Ikshvaku Kings. What was the (average) age of those kings?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/ramayana-mahabharata-31-ikshvaku-kings-what-was-the-average-age-of-those-k)

Kansa (or Kamsa) was king of Mathura when Lord Shri Krishna incarnated. Before that Ugrasena was king of Mathura. Shurasena (grandfather of Lord Shri Krishna) was king of Mathura prior to Ugrasena. When Lord Shri Krishna killed Kansa, Ugrasena again became a king of Mathura.

**Is Mathura (in which Lord Shri Krishna incarnated) same city on which Shatrughna ruled?**

Yes, please see the below explanation:

In **Madhuvana**, a daemon named Madhu used to live. Kumbhinasi was born of Ravana's maternal aunt Anala. Madhu was Kumbhinasi's husband. Later Madhu's son, the sinful Lavana started living there. ([Uttara Kanda of Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-30))

Lavana got a Trident from his father which was given by Lord Shiva to Madhu earlier. Nobody could kill Lavana when he possesses that Trident. Mandhata (one of the most powerful king from Rama's ancestors) was killed by Lavana. ([Uttara Kanda of Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-80))

Later, Shatrughana challenged Lavana while he was not carrying that Trident and killed him.  ([Uttara Kanda of Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-82))

As commanded by Lord Shri Rama, Shatrughana founded **a city on the bank of river Yamuna** which is came to be known as Madhura or Mathura. That city on the banks of Yamuna appeared beautiful like the half moon and was filled with yards, shops, streets beautiful houses, men of four orders and various articles of trade. ([Uttara Kanda of Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-83))

Comment: Instead of adding just 'source', it would be helpful if users know from where the story is e.g: Uttara Kanda of Ramayana or any other. Links will be dead someday or the other. Remember that you have to put copy pasted text in block quotes. For your own sentences or paraphrased ones, block quotes should not be used. You are doing it in the other way.

Comment: @NogShine I didn't use block quotes for my own sentences..

Comment: Well, there is another answer you did. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22525/5212. Please edit both the answers. Use block quotes for copy pasted info and not needed for your words. That's all from me.

Answer (score 2):

**Answering the question on the Birth of Lord Krishna** - [sourced from Transliteral Foundation - Ancestry : "Puranic Geneology
Hindu ancient texts mention several royal and sage families, there has been a wide research on those. This is just an attempt to load these ancestries in a standard format. Feel free to tell us any discrepancies ..........]

Sri Krishna was born during the reign of Kamsa - adopted son of Ugrasena born of his wife Padmavati. Ugrasena's ancestry can be traced to Vrishni - a descendant of Yadu. Yadu was one of the sons of Yayati, who was cursed by Sukracharya, the preceptor of Asuras to become old before his time [Mahabharata - Adi Parva Chapters 83 - 85] and how on refusal by his senior sons he curses and banishes them before handing over his kingdom to his youngest son Puru, in exchange for his youth for a thousand years.

Neither in Srimad Bhagavad Purana nor in Mahabharata is any relationship mentioned - ancestral or matrimonial - between Suvahu - son of Shatrugna and Shrutikirti - and Yadu / Yayati.

Hence **Shri Krishna was not born during the reigns of any king of the Ikshvaku Dynasty**.

Comment: Gautama Budha was from the Ikshvaku Dynasty lineage and he was born much later than Lord Krishna graced earth

Comment: I read it somewhere that Bhima (pandav) killed the descendant of Shatrugna ( 12/13 generations later) during Kurukhsetra war. I will try to get the source.