# Did anyone ever receive Lord Shiva's Trishul as a boon?

Tags: shiva, weapon, boon

In Hindu mythology,different weapons have been received from Lord Shiva.But I was wondering if there is any mention of anyone receiving Lord Shiva's Trishul as a boon.

Comment: I remember with 1 asura in Ramayan which hanuman also fought in the battle. And shiva protected hanuman from his own Trishul.. but am unsure of which Ramayan...

Comment: Durga has received (a copy of) the Trishul but not as a boon. This is the only other devi/deva with a Trishul.

Comment: Madhu also received it and from Madhu his son Lavana - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22954/12304

Answer (score 1):

None in past.Shiva still holds it.The matter of fact is that what people think of as infinite number of trishuls,brahmastra and other weapons can exist if boon is granted is false.What i mean is that there is only one unique trishul of shiva like sudarshan of vishnu these are unique weapons unlike brahmastra aur other weapons which can be created using chanting of mantras when invoked by the observer with sharp mind.Remember anyone can take shivas trishul but with very hard penance and with the order of shiva himself.Read the stories of pinaka dhamush which was that of shiva and later passed to the ancesters of sitas parent which was broken by ram in the swayambara so it was not that a new pinaka was created instead the same was passed by shiva.

Comment: You also need to cite some sort of sources for your answer :)

Comment: No its not correct.When Devi Mahashakti was created by the collected Aura of all the gods, Lord Shiva gave Her Trishul created from His own Trishul.That Trishul held by Devi is of equal power with that of Shiva.

Comment: Sudharshan Chakra was temporarily given to sandipa muni and he in turn gave it back to krishna just to  show to the world that one should get updesha through guru and get gurus anugraha

Comment: @Parth you are correct but we can't say that he gave his trishul instead it was created..the question asks does he give his trishul.

Comment: @Rickross the answer requires more than 10 scripturical proof and so i answered in a summarized manner so that further research on my correctiveness can be done on by the asker.

Comment: @Pravin RGMishra, that is not how this site works. Please edit your post to include references.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu seems you are new to hindu dharma or logical perspective.Their are no scriptures for the particular answer so i answered no.Then how can i provide evidence.

Comment: @Pravin RGMishra I am not new to the hindu dharma. There is an extensive list of scriptures available. Also, I didn't make the rules.

Comment: U sound polite @Wikash_hindi

Answer (score 1):

Parashurama received Lord Shiva's trident from him as mentioned in [Shiva Purana.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362889.html)

> 56-61. After saying this, **Śaṅkara taught him the Mantra** (esoteric formula) that is extremely difficult to obtain and the following weapons etc. viz.—extremely miraculous coat of mail named Trailokyavijaya; the Nāgapāśa (Serpentine noose), (missiles like) the Pāśupata, the Brahmāstra which is very much inaccessible, Nārāyaṇāstra, the Āgneya (Arrow with the fìregod as deity), the Vāyavya (of the wind god), the Vāruṇa (of Varuṇa the ocean-god), the Gāndharva, the Gāruḍa, the extremely wonderful weapon Jṛmbhaṇāstra, the mace, the Śakti, the Paraśu (Axe) **the trident** and the excellent Daṇḍa (baton).