# What is average lifespan of humans according to puranas in different yugas?

Tags: puranas, human

Could someone site some sources and tell what is the average lifespan of human according to Puranas in different yugas?

Comment: This has already been answered elsewere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If the Vedas say human lifespan is 100 years, how can humans live for thousands of years in previous yugas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22197/if-the-vedas-say-human-lifespan-is-100-years-how-can-humans-live-for-thousands)

Comment: @Wikash_ It doesn't list the sources from puranas which claim that human lifespan was thousand of years.