# When will the Kalyug end? Are there symbols written in scripture?

Tags: kali-yuga

When will the Kalyug end? Are there symbols written in scripture? Like men will have long hairs. Like that are there any symbols written in scriptures that this incidents will indicate the end of kaliyuga.

Comment: http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/7/38

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalki_Purana#Kali_Yuga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. According to MahAbhArata, the Kaliyuga ends with possibly total annihilation of mankind and then the mankind is regenerated with the *Kritayuga* (or *Satyuga*). During [Vana Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm), Rishi Markendeya explains Yudhishtira about the effects of Kaliyuga. He also provides the signs of end of it.

> ... And when those terrible times will be over, the creation will begin anew. And men will again be created and distributed into the four orders beginning with Brahmanas. And about that time, in order that men may increase, Providence, according to its pleasure, will once more become propitious. **And then when the Sun, the Moon, and Vrihaspati will, with the constellation Pushya 1, enter the same sign, the Krita age will begin again**. And the clouds will commence to shower seasonably, and the stars and stellar conjunctions will become auspicious. And the planets, duly revolving in their orbits, will become exceedingly propitious. And all around, there will be prosperity and abundance and health and peace.

Answer (score 2):

[Srimad Bhagwatam](http://www.srimadbhagavatam.org/canto12/chapter2.html) describes about the Kalki avatar and massacre of Sinners.

> (18) In the village of S'ambhala Lord Kalki will appear in the home of
>   the great soul, the eminent brahmin Vishnuyas'â ['the glory of
>   Vishnu']. (19-20) Mounting His swift horse Devadatta, the Lord of the
>   Universe endowed with His sword, transcendental qualities and eight
>   mystic opulences [siddhis], will subdue the reprobates. With speed
>   traveling the earth on His horse He, unrivaled in His splendor, will
>   slaughter the thieves dressing as kings by the millions. **(21) When
>   all the robbers have been killed, the minds of all the residents of
>   the towns and cities will clear up who came in touch with the breeze
>   carrying the most sacred fragrance of the [with sandalwood paste]
>   decorated body of Lord Vâsudeva.** (22) When Vâsudeva, the Supreme
>   Lord, is situated in their hearts in the transcendental form of His
>   goodness, the production of offspring will be abundant. (23) After the
>   Supreme Lord Kalki, the Lord and Master of Dharma, has incarnated,
>   Satya-yuga will begin and progeny will be created in the mode of
>   goodness [see yuga]. (24) **The moment the sun and the moon together
>   with Jupiter [Bhrihaspatî] in the same constellation [of Karkatha or
>   Cancer] enter the lunar mansion of Tishyâ [or Pushyâ, 3° 20´ to 16°
>   40´ see zodiac],  Satya-yuga [Krita] will begin.**

Answer (score 1):

As it is believed that enough warning is given and further action is awaited so no further indication is being given.Only time is awaited.In malika a lot of indication is given and according to malika things are progressing you can see Anantagopal temple at Chhatia in Orissa's Jajpur district has been waiting for
over five centuries for the arrival of Lord Jagannath, elder brother Balabhadra
and their sister Subhadra from their abode at Puri.

The priests of the temple, faithfuls and locals believe that the trinity will one day come to Chhatia abandoning their home in Puri also known as Srikhetra.
According to a prediction, Puri will be submerged due to global warming and
subsequent rise of water level in the Bay of Bengal.
Achyutananda Das, a 15th century saint of Orissa, had written about the arrival of the Lord in his famous book known as "Achutananda Malika".
He had predicted the arrival of the trinity to Chhaita after the sea engulfed the holy town and its nearby areas.

Some of Das' predictions in his Malika including drought, cyclone, same sex
marriage, public character and heat wave for the last couple of years in the countryhave come to pass, said researcher Bibhutibhusan Pal.
The Saint in his famous book 'Udhhab Bhakti Pradayani' had written, ''Jagannatha
palaibe chaka chadhi kari, Jaina rahibe Prabhu Basu je nagari (One day Lord
Jagannath will depart leaving behind his sanctum sanctorum in Puri and live in
Chhatia town),'' said Pal.

The Anantagopal temple is regarded as the second abode of Lord Jagannath after Puri. The faithfuls claim that Lord Jagannath will some day relocate to Chhatia along with his brother and sister.

The great saint Yasobanta Das :1482 D.O.B quotes

ଜାଜନଗ୍ରେ ପ୍ରଭୁ ଜନମ ହେବେ | ଜନମ ହୋଇବେ ବ୍ରାହ୍ମଣ ଭାବେ
ଶୁଣ ହୋ ବାରଂଗ କହିବା ସେ ରଂଗ ପ୍ରଭୁ ଅବତାର ଗୁଣ
ଶ୍ରୀ ବିରୋଜା ଖେତ୍ରେ ଜନମ ଲଭିବେ ଅନନ୍ତ ମିଶ୍ର ଗୃହେଣ
ୟେଥୁ ମଧ୍ୟରେ ଯେ ଗୁପୁତ ସ୍ଥାନ | ଲାଭି ମଣ୍ଡଳ ବୋଲି ଯାର ନାମ
ଦେହବନ୍ତ ହୋଇ ଖେଳିବେ ତହିଁ | ଗୋପୀ ଗୋପାଳ ଭକତକୁଂ ନେଇ

English :His almigthy will be born in Jajanagara.
Will be born as a brahmin
Now Iam describing his incarnation traits
In Biraja Khetra(Region)he will be born in Ananta Mishra family
Here in a secret place 
Labhi Mandal is place name
Where he will start his work
with his deciples and bhakats

The great saint Bhima Bhoi :1850D.O.B quotes

ଆମ୍ଭ ଜନମ ଅଣତିରିଶରେ | ଜନମ ହୋଇବୁ ବିରଜା ନଗ୍ରରେ
ପଦ୍ମାବତୀ ଗର୍ଭେ ଜନ୍ମ ହୋଇବୁ | ଖଣ୍ଡଗିରି ରେ ଧ୍ୟାନରେ ବସିବୁ
ଯେତେ ବେଳେ ନୀଳାଚଳ ଛାଡିକରି ଯିବୁ | ଯାଜପୁର ବିପ୍ରଘରେ ଯାଇ ଜନମିବୁ
ବେଲ ବୋଉଳ ବରକୋଳି ତହିଁ ନିକଟେ ଅଛି | ହୁଙ୍କା ସୁରୁପେ ନୃସିଂହ ତହିଁ ଜଗି ବସିଛି
ବାର ହାତ ତେର ଅଙ୍ଗୁଳି ହୁଙ୍କା ହୋଇବ ଉଚ୍ଚ | ତେବେ ଯାଣିବୁ ରାମଚନ୍ଦ୍ର ସତ୍ୟ ହେଲା ପ୍ରକାଶ

The great saint 'Mahapurusha' Hadi Das :1772 D.O.B quotes

ଜାଯନଗ୍ରରେ ଜାତ ହେବ | କଲ୍କି ବିଷ୍ଣୁ ବୁଝ ଧ୍ରୁବ
ନୃସିଂହ ନାମ ଅଟେ ତାର | ସେ ପୁଣି ଆସି ମୋ ଛାମୁର

I will further clarify as my research is continuing .............

Comment: You should post only one answer. Please merge two answers as one.

Comment: Some text is not properly visible  in your answer.pls.edit the text in your answer.