# Does Lord Narayana take incarnation to change era?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama, avatars, yuga

From the story of Ramayana and Mahabharata, I have come to know that Lord Narayana takes incarnation at the end of every era (yuga). And when Lord's incarnation dies then era changes (and new era starts).

For example: Lord Narayana took incarnation as Lord Rama  nearly at the end of Treta yuga. When Lord Rama died then new era (Dwapara yuga) started. Similarly,  Lord krishna took birth at the end of Dwapara yuga and on his death Kali yuga started.

Thus I believe Lord Narayana takes incarnation in every era for following purposes:

- To start new era (yuga).
- To kill all bad creatures (including demons, humans and others) so that in new era there will not any obstacle to start over Dharma as another new beginning i.e. yuga.
- To set examples of dharma by their deeds that will teach people of new era about dharma from new perspective. Means as new era is going to start so he use to set new examples (that guide towards dharma) for new people of new era.

Thus Lord Narayana took incarnation to change era or to start new era (according to my learning).

**Here is my real question**

> The thing I want to know the time of Lord Rama and Lord Krishna death. Means whether they died at end of era OR in between the era (not at end of era).

Although I believe I am right on my points but I have been asked for proof of my theory. I have proof but that proof is something like this (it is not scriptural reference because I don't read scriptures directly but instead it's from story of incarnation life. Here it is...

**Lord Krishna took birth at end of Dwapara yuga**

The wife of Bala Rama (incarnation of Sheshanag) is the kind of proof that Lord Krishna took birth at the end of Dwapara yuga. Here is how...

Revati (wife of Balarama) did born in Satya yuga and married in Dwapara yuga with Balarama. At the time of satyayuga, father of Revati couldn't find any perfect husband for his daughter in whole earth since his daughter was not an ordinary lady. So there was no any man that can properly suits Revati (as per her father's thoughts). So his father went to Brahma Loka with Revati. There they did meet Lord Brahma. Revati's father said to Brahma that I have searched whole earth but I couldn't find any suitable husband for my daughter. It seems there is not a man on earth who can marry my daughter. he asked to Brahma that Should I find husband for my daughter in other loka (world) instead of Prithvi Loka (earth)? In which Loka I can find suitable husband from my daughter?

Then Lord Brahma replied  "You will find husband for your daughter in prithvi loka (earth). Then her father replied "But I have searched whole earth and couldn't find any suitable husband for her".

Lord Brahma said "The time in which you were searching husband for your daughter, that time has been changed completely now. The speed of time in Brahma loka is extremely fast than Prithvi Loka. The little time that you spend in Brahma loka with you daughter, on that little time on Prithvi loka, 3 eras (Yuga) has been completed. On earth Satya yuga and Treta Yuga already completed (They were from Satya yuga) and **Dwapara yuga is going to end soon**. Right now in Dawapara yuga Lord Narayana is himself present on earth as his eighth incarnation. Sheshnaag also took incarnation with Lord Narayana as Balarama. And he (Balarama) is suitable husband for your daughter. So, now go to Lord Krishna and Balarama." So then they went to them and Balarama uses his plough to decrease the height of Revati (Since Revati was from Satyayuga, hence she was very tall. So Balraama decreases her height as per Dwapara yuga).

**NOTE:**  In the above story I have highlighted the Point where Brahma said Dwapara yuga is going to end and Lord Krishna is there. That simply implies that Lord Krishna was on earth at the end of Dwapara yuga. He didn't take birth in between of Dwapara yuga but instead took birth when Dwapara yuga is going to end.

Hence like this I have learned from stories of incarnation of Narayana that they take incarnation at the end of every yuga. Kalki incarnation of Narayana will also appear at the end of Kali yuga, not now.

One person claimed this as my personal theory that Lord Narayana takes incarnation at end of every era. He claims that there is no scriptural reference on this. Even if there is not scriptural reference that doesn't mean it is fake theory.

This can still be proved that Lord Narayana takes incarnation at the end of every era by finding their time of Death. That's why I am here to ask mainly about time of death of Lord Rama and Lord Krishna because those incarnations of Narayana was era changing incarnation. If they were born at end of era and died at end of era then there will be no doubt that Lord Narayana always takes incarnation at the end of era.

So what was the time of death of Rama and Krishna?

Comment: Sri Rama was born in Treta Yuga not at the end of Satya Yuga.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria whoops, my mistake but corrected now. He was born and died at end of Treta yuga. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: I didn't say he was born at the end of Treta Yuga, neither at the start nor at the end.

Comment: What about the other avatars like Matsya, Kurma, Varaha etc? Are you talking about only human avatars here?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I didn't say that, I am saying that. I have shown a little story also that proves this thing.

Comment: @Rickross I never said that Lord Narayana takes incarnation **only at the end of era**. I said He use to take incarnation at the end of era, that doesn't mean he won't take incarnation in between era. 10 incarnation has been shown which has been taken or will be taken. And era are only 4. Don't get wrong understanding of my question. I never used **only** word in my question. Please read it again. And what about the proof that I have shown about Krishna took birth at end of Dwapar yuga (as a story)?

Comment: Its ok..not a problem..@Rishabh

Comment: @Rickross Actually, Scriptures might not directly mentioned this But we can come to know about this by conversation happened between characters of incarnation story (One example I have shown in my ques.). As an another example: Lord Krishna once said that Son of Abhumanyu will play key role in yugantar (conversion of era). This conversation also implies that Lord krishna was present at the end of era. Like this if we read story carefully then we can come to know that Rama and Krishna was doing everything at the end of era.

Comment: Kali dint start immediately after disappearance of Krishna. Kali I guess started after departure of king Parikshit who was the son of Abhimanyu and Grandson of Arjuna. Anyways krishna says in Geeta that Avatar's purpose is 1.Annihilate demons,2. Save Saintly ppl and 3. Reestablish Dharma. Generally at the end of era ppl become demonic so He appears at the end of era.

Comment: No. Change of yuga is usually a side effect of the completion of the avatara

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande First of all, I didn't meant that Kali yuga started on the next second of disappearance of Krishna. Next era can be start after a day/month or even year after death of Krishna. That small amount of time doesn't matter in a long era. And second thing, The point that you shown about Kind Parikshit that point I have already mentioned in my last comment (just before ur comment). And this example of your also proved that Krishna was there at the end of Dwapar yuga.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I am here to primarily prove that Lord always takes incarnation at end of era. And your comments kinda favors my believe. And I am also curious to know that those side effects that you mentioned are whether positive or negative?

Comment: @rishabh but multiple avataras happened in satya yuga. Another example - parasurama and Rama both existed in treatment.  So your hypothesis is disproved.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Parshuram was ansha avatar. Narayana himself didn't take birth in form of Parshuram. That's why Parshuram is called ansha avatar of Narayan same as Hanuman is ansha avatar of Shiva..

Comment: Doesn't matter. He is regarded as one of the main 10

Comment: @moonstar2001 What do you mean by **main 10**? Lord Narayana has only 10 incarnation in which no one is main. Means no one is superior and no one is inferior. All has their own importance. I am not talking about who is main incarnation and who is not. I am just saying that one of the Lord incarnation always appear at the end of era.

Comment: The main 10 are the dasavatara. Narayana has many more avataras. You misread my point. "I am just saying that one of the Lord incarnation always appear at the end of era." And I am saying this isn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"Does Lord Narayana take incarnation to change era?"*

**Not necessarily**. There are few [*AvatAra*-s which are listed for Vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19617/1049), but there may be many others which are not that much famous. IMO, we cannot define when the lord should take an incarnation. Also not everyone of them were born at the end of an era, as there are only 4 era-s.

---

> *"The thing I want to know the time of Lord Rama and Lord Krishna death. Means whether they died at end of era OR in between the era"*

Yes, **End of the era**, as you rightly mentioned! This is specific only to RAma & Krishna.
Another *AvatAra* of ParashurAma was before Shri RAma and is believed to be long lived.

As per MahAbhArata's [ShAnti parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c039.htm):

> In the **Treta age I shall take birth as [Parashu]Rama** in the race of Bhrigu, and exterminate the Kshatriyas who will become proud of their strength and possessions. **Towards the close of Treta and the beginning of Dwapara, I shall take birth as Rama**, the son of Dasaratha in Iskshaku's royal line. ... **Towards the close of the Dwapara and beginning of the Kali ages**, I shall again appear in the world taking birth in the city of Mathura for the purpose of slaying Kansa

Similar thing is said by Krishna himself after the death of Duryodhana during [Shalya Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09060.htm):

> **Krishna replied**, saying, "Thou art always described as bereft of wrath, and righteous-souled and devoted to righteousness! Calm thyself, therefore, and do not give way to wrath! **Know that the Kali age is at hand**. Remember also the vow made by the son of Pandu! ...

Comment: First of all, I never said that Lord takes incarnation **only** at the end of era. I said he takes incarnation at end of every era that doesn't mean that he never takes other incarnation in between of era. And second thing is... Those other incarnation that you are mentioning, those were not born from womb. Like Matasya, Varaha and other didn't took birth like Rama and Krishna and never live a specific age on earth. In any case, do you think, it is just coincident that Lord took incarnation at the end of eras or there is purpose behind it?

Comment: @Rishabh, out of many incarnations only 2 of them have scripture basis to have taken birth at end of era. I have just concentrated on your core Qn (highlighted). Personally my opinion is that it's a coincidence, because the timeline of any era is fixed, I.e. 4800-3600-2400-1200 ... Which means that the era ends by itself. So Rama & Krishna birth just happened towards the end.

Comment: Out of 4 eras you have shown 2 in which Narayana took incarnation at the end of era. Remaining 2 eras in which Kalki will take birth at the end of Kali yuga. I hope you don't have any doubt that Kalki will not take birth in upcoming few years but instead at the end of Kali yuga to start Satyuga again. So 3 eras proven in which Narayana takes birth at end of era? for me yes. Remaining 1 era(Satyga). Vahmana avatar of Narayana took birth as child of Deva mata Aditi. His time of birth and death also need to consider like Rama/Krishna to prove Vishnu appear at end of every 4 Era.

Comment: @Rishabh, though I am not a firm believer of various *AvatAra*-s, **according to scriptures**, "Kalki" is supposed to be born during a *Kritayuga* which will be established after the end of a *Kaliyuga*. See: [When will the Kalki avatar be born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19603/1049). Your guess is correct about RAma & Krishna regarding their existence during end of an era.

Comment: Alright, your point seems valid But that means Kali yuga won't be witness of any of Lord's incarnation? Lord never show up in Kali yuga like prev. yuga? I wonder why!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06028.htm

Lord Krishna told this why and when he takes avatars.

> Whenever, O Bharata, loss of piety and the rise of impiety occurreth, on those occasions do I create myself. For the protection of the righteous and for the destruction of the evil doers, for the sake of establishing Piety, I am born age after age. He who truly knoweth my divine birth and work to be such, casting off (his body) is not born again; (on the other hand) he cometh to me, O Arjuna.

So Lord Vishnu takes avatars when there is loss of piety and rise of impiety, for destruction of evil doers, for establishing piety and for the protection of the righteous, not to change eras

Answer (score 0):

No. Vishnuji takes avatars to re-establish his dharma or Vaishnavism. He says so himself in Gita and Vishnu Sahasranaam:

> **परित्राणाय साधूनां विनाशाय च दुष्कृताम् | धर्मसंस्थापनार्थाय** सम्भवामि युगे युगे || Gita 4.8||

> To protect the righteous, to annihilate the wicked, and to reestablish the principles of dharma I appear on this earth, age after age.

So there is no mention of him wanting to start or end Yugas / ages / eras. He also takes avatar at changing point like Krishanji, but **he does not himself change the era. Era will change regardless of when Vishnuji wants to incarnate. The time of eras is already fixed.**