# What was the age of Hanuman when Bheema met him?

Tags: mahabharata, hanuman

Here is a question out of curiosity:

What was the approximate age of Hanuman, when Bheema met him in the Mahabharata?

Answer (score 6):

Age? Does one know when Hanuman was born? He was born waaay back, even before Rama. And has completed the entire Treta Yuga into Dwapara. Its impossible to track his age as we do not have a systematic calendar of those times.

Comment: Not one treta yuga, four dwapara yugas. The Treta Yuga Ramayana happened is 24th and Mahabharata happened is 28th dwapara yuga.

Comment: Exactly so. And between each Chaturyuga, God knows how much "bridge period" there had been.

Answer (score 4):

Exact age of Lord Hanuman is hard to find But still we can get estimate age of Hanuman at the time when he met Bheema. Here is how...

As par [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19586/does-lord-narayana-take-incarnation-to-change-era/#answer-19618) it's clear that Lord Rama took birth at the end of Treta yuga, So as Hanuman. As par the same answer it is also clear that Lord krishna took birth at the end of Dwapar yuga, so as Bheema.

Here 2 pints are clear that Lord Rama and Lord krishna took birth at the end of Treta yuga and Dwapar yuga respectively. Since Hanuman took birth little earlier than Rama. And Bheema was Present when Lord krishna was on earth, So that simply implies that Lord Hanuman born at the end of Treta yuga and met with Bheema at the end of Dwapar yuga Since Bheema was born at the end of Dwapar yuga.

By this calculations we conclude that age of Hanuman was nearly about (if not exact age) 1 yuga when he meet Bheema. How his age is 1 yuga? Because Hanuman born at the end of Treta yuga and met with Bheema at the end of Dwapar yuga, so....

**End of Trata yuga - End of Dwapar yuga = Dwapar yuga (age of Dwapar yuga)**.

Hence the estimate age of Hanuman will be equal to the age of Dwapar yuga. Now to get an estimate of Hanuman's age we just need to find out age of Dwapar yuga which in not an tough task to find. Lots of info available on net about age of all yuga and here I am showing wiki's info about age of Dwapar yuga.

As par [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvapara_Yuga) age of Dwapar yuga was 864,000 years. By this info we can conclude that estimate age of Hanuman at the time when he met Bheema should have been nearly about 864,000 years. As I am repeating again it is just an estimate. Exact age is not that easy to find But estimate age is not that tough to find.

Comment: Hello Rishabh, B'date of Lord Rama is 10th Jan, 5114 BC. So it may be 7131 years ago from now. as per https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8663/isr-says-birthdate-of-lord-rama-is-10th-january-5114-bc-what-about-kalki-avatar answer.  Hanuman and Rama age difference is not too much, I think.  Now you said "By this info we can conclude that estimate age of Hanuman at the time when he met Bheema should have been nearly about 864,000 years."    Why is there very huge difference between this calculation? 864,000 years and 7131 years?

Comment: @samsol You figure of 7131 is totally wrong dear. It is impossible. First of all, Rama live as King of Ayodhya for more than 5000 years. And There is whole one yuga (Dwapar yuga) gap between Rama's birth and now. So your are saying the age of Dwapar yuga was only 7000 years? Really? An yuga can't be that small. Yuga's age is in between lakhs, Not in thousands. Another pont is, even 5000 years of kali yuga has been passed. With this figure of your, you are indirectly saying that Rama was born in Dwapar yuga, not in Treta yuga.

Comment: @SamSol: 4,000 + 400 + 400 = 4,800 divine years (= 1,728,000 human years) = `1 Satya Yuga[8]`
3,000 + 300 + 300 = 3,600 divine years (= 1,296,000 human years) = `1 Treta Yuga[8]`
2,000 + 200 + 200 = 2,400 divine years (= 864,000 human years) = `1 Dvapara Yuga[8]`
1,000 + 100 + 100 = 1,200 divine years (= 432,000 human years) = `1 Kali Yuga[8]`
12,000 divine year = 4 Yugas (= 4,320,000 human years) = `1 Mahā-Yuga (also is equaled to 12000 Daiva (divine) Yuga)[8]`
[2*12,000 = 24,000 divine year = 12000 revolutions of sun around its dual][8]