# When will Lord Kalki appear and where is Shambal?

Tags: avatars, kali-yuga, kalki

When will Kalki avatar reveal himself and where is Shambal?

Comment: Related! [When will the Kalki avatar be born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/when-will-the-kalki-avatar-be-born)

Comment: Your question is partially a duplicate!