# Is Shangri-La, Tibet will be called as Shambhala, Birth place of Lord Kalki?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, bhagavata-purana, vishnu-purana, kalki

1) Where exactly `Shambhala village` is located? Is Shangri-La, Tibet will be called as Shambhala, Birth place of Lord Kalki?

2) Why Lord Kalki, Son of VishnuYashyas will be born out of India in Shambhala village in Tibet?

3) Are there any previous Avatars of Lord born or lived in different geographical locations or countries other than India, SriLanka?

4) Who is Mother and Siblings of Lord Kalki?

5) What are the key differences between Kalki Avatar and ParushuRama Avatar?

6) Where will Goddess Lakshmi be born during Lord Kalki Avatara?

7) How many years Lord Kalki will rule and re-establish 'Dharma' on earth?

Comment: Shangri-La is an invented place by a Western author that appeared in the Western novel "Lost Horizon"

Comment: Answers for questions 1,2 and 6 will be based on speculation. Rest are answered in Kalki Purana. See [What is the story of Kalki (tenth avatar of God Vishnu)?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/579/3500)

Comment: I think the place is Simhala , and it corresponds to the Tamil land or SriLanka.

Comment: @Yogi: The place is not Simhala but what I came to know the exact place is `Shambhala` only but it's not related to SriLanka.  It's even mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatham regarding place name.