# Does shambala village exists?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, belief, history

[Shambala](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shambhala) village. Does this village has existed at any point of time in history or any yuga ? Or it is a mythical kingdom which is going to be show up in future?

We all have heard that, when evil takes over the world lord kalki comes from this village in order to protect good.

Can someone put light on this topic please.

My question is , Are there any mythological stories on this village? If so, Is this place real like ayodhya, dwaraka, or Lanka? If so, where exactly is this place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14207/is-shangri-la-tibet-will-be-called-as-shambhala-birth-place-of-lord-kalki

Comment: May be I haven't used proper search terms I guess. :(

Comment: @SwiftPushkar the other one has so many questions. But this is one straight forward question on village. I would prefer it to not to mark as duplicate. Any how its admins choice. Thanks for pointing though.

Comment: Yes agree , but some of the answers of your this question are  provided in the other one. I commented  in order to avoid duplicate  Questions.Lets see wht mods.think.

Comment: Hi! This question leads to opinion based answers since different people have different opinions on Shambala. Some say it is in Himalayas (Tibet), some say in South India, some say it is in other dimension. So, i'm closing  it as it leads to opinion based answers.